# Java ConcurrentModificationException Error while writing in Excel

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, apache-poi, runtime-error

I have a java class which I use to write a specific String in a specific cell, depending on the input.
I use Apache POI.

My Class has two writing methods. One for single line writing and one for writing multiple times.
The method for multiple writing seems to be my trouble, I think :(

here is my writing class:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class TrueExcelWriter {
     
    public TrueExcelWriter(){}
    
    private static int findRow(XSSFSheet sheet, String cellContent) {
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
                    if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(cellContent)) {
                        return row.getRowNum();  
                    }
                }
                    
                if (cell.getCellType().equals(CellType.NUMERIC)){
//                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
//                        System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
//                            
//                    } else {
                        long lookup = (long) cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        String catcher = Long.toString(lookup);
                            
                        if(catcher.equals(cellContent)){
                            return row.getRowNum();
                        }
//                  }
                        
                }
                    
            }
        }               
        return 0;
    }
    
    public void WriteToAll(String suchobjekt, String ID, String SPID) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        
    
        final String fileName = "C:/Temp/TTT.xlsx";
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        
        int colnr = 0; 
        
        switch (suchobjekt) {
            case "option1":
                colnr = 15; 
                break;
             case "option2":
                colnr = 16; 
                break;
            case "option3":
                colnr = 999; 
                break;
        }
        
        Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
        
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            
            if(nextRow.getRowNum()==0){ 
            continue; //just skip the rows if row number is X or Y
            }
            
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell nextCell = cellIterator.next();
                
                String y = nextCell + "";
                
                if(y.equals(ID)){
                    
                    Row r = sheet.getRow(nextRow.getRowNum());
                    if (r == null) {
                        // First cell in the row, create
                        r = sheet.createRow(nextRow.getRowNum());
                    }
                    
                    Cell c = r.getCell(colnr);
                    if (c == null) {
                        // New cell
                        c = r.createCell(colnr, CellType.STRING);
                    }
                    c.setCellValue(SPID);
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        input.close();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        wb.write(output);
        output.close();
        wb.close();
        
    }
 
    public void WriteTo(String suchobjekt, String ID, String SPID) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    
        final String fileName = "C:/Temp/TTT.xlsx";
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        
        int colnr = 0;
        int rownr;
        
        switch (suchobjekt) {
            case "option1":
                colnr = 15; 
                break;
             case "option2":
                colnr = 16; 
                break;
            case "option3":
                colnr = 999; 
                break;
        }
        
        rownr = findRow(sheet, ID);
        
        Row r = sheet.getRow(rownr);
        if (r == null) {
            // First cell in the row, create
            r = sheet.createRow(rownr);
        }
        
        Cell c = r.getCell(colnr); 
        if (c == null) {
            // New cell
            c = r.createCell(colnr, CellType.STRING);
        }
        c.setCellValue(SPID);
        
        input.close();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        wb.write(output);
        output.close();
        wb.close();
        
    
    }
    
}
```

I am using the following code to write something in my excel file:

```
try {
     ter.WriteToAll("option2", "abc", "done");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
               System.out.println("Error!  "+ex);
    }
```

My excel file currently looks like this:

```
...14   15    16   ...
  ... | ID  | ...
  ... | abc | done
  ... | abc | done
  ... | abc | done
  ... | def | 
  ... | ghi | 
  ... | jkl | 
  ... | jkl | 
  ... | jkl | 
  ... | mno | 
  ... | mno | 
  ... | mno |
```

If I use the method from above and used it for all IDs, everything works **except** for ID "***def***"!

I don't know why this does not work for this single one. :(

If I try the single line writing function for this ID, it works.

But I font know why the multiple writing function does not work for this one.

I am getting the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1208)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$ValueIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1253)
    at easypackaging.TrueExcelWriter.WriteToAll(TrueExcelWriter.java:88)
    at easypackaging.TEST_TrueVerladen.actionPerformed(TEST_TrueVerladen.java:172)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

`TrueExcelWriter` is the class where I run the `ter.WriteToAll`.

I googled the error but I was not able to solve my problem with what I found. :(

If needed, I can upload my complete (censored) excel sheet for you.

Can you guys help me out?

Sincerely yours,
Shathos

**UPDATE:**

I wrote a new, simpler algorithm for my multiple line writing which worked for me. :) Thank's for the help!

New function:

```
public void WriteToAll_TV(String ID, String SPID) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        
        final String fileName = "C:/Temp/TTT.xlsx";
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
        CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        
        XSSFCell cell;
        XSSFRow row;
        
        int colnr = 15;
        int rownr = 0;
        
        rownr = findRow(sheet, ID);
        
        for(int i = rownr; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            
            String y = row.getCell(colnr)+"";
            
            if(y.equals(ID)){
                row.createCell(16).setCellValue(createHelper.createRichTextString(SPID));
            }
            
        }
        
        input.close();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        wb.write(output);
        output.close();
        wb.close();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the sheet by adding rows while iterating over the rows. That is where the ConcurrentModificationException is coming from.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I think I get what you mean. I wrote a new, simpler algorithm which works for me. I updated my topic with an updated version of my multiple writing function! Thank you for your hep! :)